# Esri x and y coordinate confusión

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, esri-geodatabase

I am trying to figure out which coordinate system x and y are in and trying to understand the data from the Esri site.

datasource: [DATA](https://services6.arcgis.com/ZxFYx8rM0YBg9sBr/arcgis/rest/services/L%C3%ADneas_de_Transmisi%C3%B3n/FeatureServer/0/query?f=json&where=1%3D1&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&maxAllowableOffset=1.0583354500042348&outFields=*&outSR=102100&resultOffset=0&resultRecordCount=2000&quantizationParameters=%7B%22mode%22%3A%22view%22%2C%22originPosition%22%3A%22upperLeft%22%2C%22tolerance%22%3A1.0583354500042348%2C%22extent%22%3A%7B%22xmin%22%3A-7982699.702671254%2C%22ymin%22%3A2022120.446410212%2C%22xmax%22%3A-7618910.389175869%2C%22ymax%22%3A2257455.540297863%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A102100%2C%22latestWkid%22%3A3857%7D%7D%7D)

In the data each FID represents a Polyline, the coordinate is in the geometry attribute. Sometimes the first given value (0 -> 0,1) represents the stating point of the line, and some times x0 and x1 gets inverter, the dame happend to y0 and y1.

For example:

FID: 124

```
0:{0:142239, 1:104776}
1:{0:-1345, 1:2253}
```

The 1 represents the difference between origin and next point.

When you represent the data, it should be displayed as:

```
0:{0:142239, 1:109282}
1:{0:-1345, 1:-2253}
```

FID: 127

```
0:{0:142239, 1:104776}
1:{0:-13221, 1:3123}
```

The 1 represents the difference between origin and next point.

When you represent the data, it should be displayed as:

```
0:{0:140894, 1:107029}
1:{0:-13221, 1:-3123}
```

Another thing, which coordinate system x and y are this data in?
FID: 124 origin is supposed to be nearby: 18.929 -70.358
FID: 127 origin is supposed to be nearby: 18.909,-70.370

Comment: Look at the layer metadata, [at the level above](https://services6.arcgis.com/ZxFYx8rM0YBg9sBr/arcgis/rest/services/L%C3%ADneas_de_Transmisi%C3%B3n/FeatureServer/0), which reports "Spatial Reference: 102100 (3857)". The units in Web Mercator are nominally "meters" but actually of no particular meaning. Tiny values near the origin keep you on Null Island.

Comment: And if you request [geojson](https://services6.arcgis.com/ZxFYx8rM0YBg9sBr/arcgis/rest/services/L%C3%ADneas_de_Transmisi%C3%B3n/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&outSR=&f=pgeojson) (`f=pgeojson`) instead of Esri json (`f=json`), you'll get lon, lat in EPSG:4326 https://i.stack.imgur.com/zahOk.png

Comment: @user2856 Thanks for your help. How did you manage to organize the data? I noticed that the dataset got from the 'f=pgeojson' refered to EPSG:3857 and the data seems to be lat and lot inverter, and the decimal point misplaced.

Comment: No, the data returned from that query is in EPSG:4326 not EPSG:3857.  i.e. latitude and longitude (Y, X) in decimal degrees. The coordinates are reversed as that is the correct axis order for EPSG:4326 and there is no misplacement of decimal point, the coordinates are decimal degrees not metres.   If you read it as GeoJSON, i.e use a library that understands GeoJSON you don't need to worry about that.